# Аналог excel таблицы

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

как лучше сделать аналог excel таблицы, только в html? Например, свободное добавление строк, столбцов по аналогии, как в excel. Я так понимаю, это будет с помощью кнопок (добавить столбец, добавить строку). Но если помимо этого это еще и динамическая таблица, данные которой по нажатию должны уходить в БД и т.п.
Может есть похожие проекты в открытом доступе или статьи? Я ничего похожего не нашел=(
Спасибо за внимание=)

Comment: То, что вы описываете, похоже на Google docs. Это вам не подходит?

Comment: @ling а у гугл докс есть возможности связи с локальным сервером mysql?

Comment: увы, не знаю. Думаю, можно подцепиться по api, правда, не в режиме реального времени.

Comment: У меня был похожий опыт типа таблицы, в вашем случае кнопки на добавление/удаление строк, столбцов, на редактирование ячеек ну и пересчет на стороне сервера при добавлении, удалении, обновление конкретной ячейки если редактирование и отрисовка всей таблицы по новой, так будет правильней нежели обновлять конкретную ячейку, безопасней я бы даже сказал. Готового функционала не знаю, сам по тихоньку до всего дошел, нужно начать делать и спрашивать и тогда разберетесь, а сообщество подскажет как то или иное действие сделать лучше.